# How to send one way notification to set of users in Teams (apps) in Azure Subscription from different subscription using Bot services?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-teams

**Problem:**
I was trying to send messages to list of users in one AD domain/subscription to another AD domain subscription. I have used the company communicator provided by Teams app (refer link below).

**Note:**
I have used the "Company Communicator" to send one way Notifications.

**Flow:**
[A] Azure subscription (Bot Services). ---------Notification-------> [B] Azure subscription (Teams App)

**For Reference "Company communicator" Architecture:**
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/wiki/Solution-overview

**Expected:**
I would need to send one way Notification to Teams App in a different AD domain/Azure Subscription from a different AD Domain/Azure Subscription.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, How to send one way notification to set of users in Teams (apps) in Azure Subscription from different subscription using Bot services?

Comment: There's no issue doing this at all, you just need the correct details for the conversation (conversation id, serviceurl), but your bot has to be installed by the target users. Read more on Proactive Messages for Teams to understand it better - it's the concept used in Company Communicator

Comment: @HilitionGiesenow,let me crosscheck the arch ones again. Could you please clarify the service url exactly which one u r referring to?

Comment: Please read the docs, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging . ServiceUrl is one of the values you get from the user, together with conversation id, to be able to proactively message them. It will be in the sample you are using as well

Answer (score 0):

@Nanda: Could you please have a look on below screen shot for service url.

[image]

Comment: thnks for ur time let me cross check it.

Comment: @HilitionGiesenow, thnks for ur time let me cross check it.